# Unable to display all properties of an object passed between amx pages

Tags: oracle, maf

I am facing a difficulty in displaying the properties of an object passed from an amx page to another. My aim is to display all the fields of an object of class employee{String name,int age,String phone} on a separate amx page. But I'm only able to display the name field.

[Here is my empList.amx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVeFn.png)

[Here is my EmpDetails.amx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGZR7.png)

The reultant display on my simulator for EmpDetails.amx shows just the employee.name property and nothing else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to manually add other properties in to the bindings. Here you added only the 'name' property in the row. name property automatically bind with the `Listview` object while drag and dropping ListView component from the palette.

**Follow the below procedure**

- Select the bindings tab in the amx page where you defined the
  ListView.
- Select the object collection and click on the edit button (pencil).
- Inside the edit popup, drop the needed properties in to the binding
  region and click apply button
- otherwise add the values manually in the *************pageDef.xml
  file. Xml link provided in the bindings tab.
  [image]

[image]